# How to externalize Hibernate Entities?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jar, entity, external

I'm working on a Java/Spring/Hibernate based web app, developed in Eclipse.

This web app is actually two different projects that duplicate a couple Hibernate entity classes, as well as their respective Hibernate repository classes.  Obviously, it would be nice to take the duplicated code, and move it into an external JAR file or something.

From the Hibernate documentation, I know that I'm supposed to put the entity class in a new JAVA project that contains a `persistence.xml` file.  I also know that I can then export this project to a JAR, and include it in the classpath of my main projects.  Further, I know that I'm supposed to reference this JAR from my `hibernate.cfg.xml` in my main project.

For some reason, it doesn't seem to be quite so simple with the project I'm working on right now.

Here are the questions:

1. in my external project that holds the shared code, can I include the Hibernate Repository class it it too?  How should this be noted in the `persistence.xml`, if it indeed needs to be at all?
2. In my external JAR, how minimal can the `persistence.xml` be?  For instance, the main project already configures the hibernate dialect, so can I leave that out of this external JAR's `persistence.xml`?
3. From the Hibernate docs, I know that I can reference my external JAR file using the `<jar-file>` tag in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`.  So what if my project doesn't have a `hibernate.cfg.xml`?  We have a configuration xml for Spring that gives an `annotatedClasses` property to the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.  I'm not having much luck finding examples of referencing external JAR files with the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.

I've tried searching around on this site, but haven't found anything similar enough to help me out yet.  Apologies if this is a duplicate post, or a stupidly obvious question or something.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

OK, so it looks like what I ultimately need to know is, supposing I've included `"MY_TEST.jar"` in my classpath, and further supposing `"MY_TEST.jar"` has one annotated Hibernate class: `src.shared.myEntity.java`

How would I go about referencing this entity class with the below Spring configuration excerpt? (keep getting `IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class` pretty much no matter what I try)

```
<bean id="my.postgres.sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource"
        ref="my.postgres.dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>src.app.EntityA</value>
        <value>src.app.EntityB</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    .........
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't have the concept of a repository.
Spring does.

Hibernate doesn't care where the persistent entities classes are.
They must be in the classpath,
that's all.
Whether they're in one,
two,
or three jars doesn't matter if all these jars are in the classpath.

Organize your projects as you would like and just make sure you don't have two different hibernate configuration files in the classpath.
I would use a project to hold all the common entities and maybe their associated repositories and let the main project define the hibernate configuration file.

If the shared class fully qualified name is src.shared.myEntity,
then the spring config should have the following lines:

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    ...
    <value>src.shared.myEntity</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Your wording is confusing,
so I'll check what I considered obvious,
but which is perhaps not.
The fully qualified name of a class is composed of its full package name, followed by the name of the class,
without .class or .java extension.
The jar must contain the .class file,
not the .java file.
The hierarchy of the directories in the jar must exactly map the hierarchy of the packages.
So if your entity looks like this:

```
package src.shared;

@Entity
public class myEntity {
    // ...
}
```

The jar should have,
at its root,
a `src` directory,
containing a `shared` directory,
containing a `myEntity.class` file.

PS: having `src` as a root package name is really strange.
Why don't you respect the convention: `com.yourcompany.yourproject`...?

PPS: a class name should always start with a capital letter:
`MyEntity` and not `myEntity`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response!  Sorry, I misspoke about the repository thing.

I have my external jar in my classpath, but I'm having trouble referencing it using the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean properties in my Spring configuration.  Again, the Hibernate docs give a clear example of how this is done with a hibernate.cfg.xml file, but the original project architect decided not to include this, but rather configure everything through Spring's configuration.  Everything is compiling, but spring can't find my external Entity classes

Comment: Then show us the spring configuration which you have a problem with, and tell us which exception occurs (stack trace). But spring doesn't care about jars either. If some class is in the classpath, it will find it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean to be confusing.  The entity and package structure I'm looking at does follow convention...apparently I fail at typing :)  Also, that is interesting, according to what you posted, what I have should be working just fine.  I do have everything setup as you suggest, and the entity from my JAR file is referenced like you said, from within the spring config file in my main project.  I must still be missing something...hm....

Comment: hey, by the way, thank you for taking the time to help me out!